# "No database selected" error from mysql db and myphp site

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting 'No database selected' everytime I login to my php website. The backend is MySQL database. The following code is in my database.php file. I appreciate any help on the issue. Thank you.

```
{ 
    public $conn; 

    function __construct($server, $user_name, $pass, $db) { 
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $pass); 
        mysql_select_db($db, $this->conn); 
    } 

    function __destruct() { 
        mysql_close($this->conn); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: show how do you create the db object dear asoiaf character?

Comment: You tag php 5.5 but reading [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) docs: `Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0` So you should not use `mysql_*` functions!

Comment: It's actually 5.4.4. Is it still deprecated?. It's an old website that I am trying to test on LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you do this?

```
 mysql_select_db($db, $this->conn) 
      || die ("select_db failed: " . mysql_error($this->conn));
```

It may halp you understand what's going wrong.

Also please stop using the mysql_ apis.

Comment: I get select_db failed: I am not sure what I should do next.

Comment: Try to figure out whether the database for which the name is in `$db` actually exists on the server, and whether the user name and password you're using to connect has the privileges to access that particular database.